# Curl command line for consuming webServices?

Tags: web-services, testing, curl

Do you guys know how I can use the Curl command line to POST SOAP to test a web service?

I have a file (soap.xml) which has all the soap message attached to it I just don't seem to be able to properly post it.

Thanks!

Answer (score 43, accepted):

Posting a string:

```
curl -d "String to post" "http://www.example.com/target"
```

Posting the contents of a file:

```
curl -d @soap.xml "http://www.example.com/target"
```

Comment: Usually this header is also necessary: -H "Content-Type: application/soap+xml;charset=UTF-8"

Comment: Getting `HTTP/1.1 415 Unsupported Media Type` means the content-type header is missing or wrong. Try one of the ones suggested here (`application/soap+xml` didn't work for me, but `text/xml` worked)

Comment: I also had to add `; action=http://tempuri.org/WhateverAction` to the `Content-Type` header.

Answer (score 34):

For a SOAP 1.2 Webservice, I normally use

```
curl --header "content-type: application/soap+xml" --data @filetopost.xml http://domain/path
```

Answer (score 27):

Wrong. 
That doesn't work for me.

For me this one works:

```
curl 
-H 'SOAPACTION: "urn:samsung.com:service:MainTVAgent2:1#CheckPIN"'   
-X POST 
-H 'Content-type: text/xml'   
-d @/tmp/pinrequest.xml 
192.168.1.5:52235/MainTVServer2/control/MainTVAgent2
```

Comment: epic! thanks for taking the time to post the ACTUAL working example!

Answer (score 8):

```
curl -H "Content-Type: text/xml; charset=utf-8" \
-H "SOAPAction:" \
-d @soap.txt -X POST http://someurl
```

Comment: This works fro me. However, I need to read a value in soap.txt from a file.
`code`
<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:usa="http://www.xyz.com/SAFSubscriberProvision/">
   <soapenv:Header/>
   <soapenv:Body>
      <saf:SubscriberID MSISDN="254727849628"/>
   </soapenv:Body>
</soapenv:Envelope> `code`

Comment: `-d @soap.txt` parameter provides what you want.

Answer (score 4):

If you want a fluffier interface than the terminal, http://hurl.it/ is awesome.