# Using SOAP on windows

Tags: php, powershell

I need to connect to a SOAP endpoint from a windows machine, however, the PowerShell  `New-WebServiceProxy` cmdlet fails to process the WSDL. I can't change the WSDL, and I have the connection working in PHP.

I'm not too sure about using PHP just as a scripting tool. What other tools might be available to get the SOAP endpoint running, and C# seems overkill for this.

other features I need in the scripting tool
 - watch/open a file that is created
 - find rows that a different in the Files (CSV)

Comment: Depending on how complex your web service is, you may use a simple cli tool like curl in your script. See [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/84007/curl-command-line-for-consuming-webservices) question for example. I would prefer my own C# or Java program for your task, but if you think that is overkill you still have options. :)

Comment: What is the error message you got from the PowerShell output?

Comment: New-WebServiceProxy : Unable to import binding 'Binding' from namespace 'urn:Magento'.